# Why are all the fans in football games in the same part of the stands rather than spread out?

Tags: football, english-premier-league

I understand there's a limit to the number of fans due to coronavirus, but why are they all just in one quadrant of the stands with the rest of the stands empty rather than spread throughout the whole stands? Surely this gets rid of the whole point of limiting the number of fans (to allow people to distance).

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. This is a good first question, but it could be improved by saying in which league(s) or match(es) you've seen this happen. There is a great variety of both sociopolitical response to the pandemic and of necessity for distancing.

Comment: I don't know of any exception to this, at least in any major leagues. e.g. champions league and premier league there doesn't seem to be any game were the spectators are spread across the whole stands.

Answer (score 1):

Opening less stands is cost effective and requires less staff being exposed to possible infections. Also watching fans in fewer stands is easier for the security staff.

The limits are not just for distancing on the stands. In fact, the stands are the least of the problems they have. When the fans are all seated they don't pose much of a threat to their neighbours anymore (as long as they keep their required distance).

The limits have several other reasons as well:

- avoid bigger crowds at the entrances and on premises
- avoid overcrowded public transport
- retain a reasonable number of infections in case of a spreading